# Serial Graphical LCD control with Python over SPI from Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, driver, raspberry-pi, spi, lcd

I want to use the Sharp LS027B7DH01 LCD display here: http://www.sharpmemorylcd.com/resources/LS027B7DH01_Spec.pdf

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Sharp-Microelectronics/LS027B7DH01/?qs=muFWWzTLGEIPdePNc1A/NQ==

I need to control it with a Raspberry Pi programmed in python 2.7. It is a 400x240 display controlled via SPI, but no controller chip part number is identified. There are only 4 commands to write to it, and each display line is written one at at time. I've not been able to find an existing driver to use with it (but honestly, I'm not sure I am searching for the right things)

I *could* write a driver from the ground up to do text and graphics and everything, but it seems like a lot of work, and surely something like this has to already exist...

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to create bitmaps of the entire screen area with other tools such as pybmp, PIL, etc and simply dump that image to the LCD for display.